# Creating a node with a grid

Tags: drupal, view, gallery

i have a album overview created in views where i can see all subalbums thumbnails in a grid, thats good.

but when i click a image it goes to the album (node) that is containing all images, how do i make those images show in a grid?

So my question is: Can i create a view and say like: this view should only show in these content types?

i have tried Grid field formatter module, but i dont see how it should work.

Any other premade modules that i can make use of in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since you have created this with views and you seem to at least have some decent working knowledge of Drupal. I highly recommend that you actually fire your click through back to the same view but this time with a contextual filter applied to it.

for example if your views link were mysite.com/galleries - all galleries displayed

your gallery thumbnail link would go to mysite.com/galleries/gallery1

Gallery1 should be taxonomy or some other means to filter, based on your criteria.

Views is one of the most powerful tools I have ever seen and you can even create multiple pages, blocks, etc... of any view. This way you can have a completey different view with the same backbone run off the same content type, taxanomy, etc...

This is a current work in progress site that does just this
[Working Example of multiple views displaying products in different ways - WIP](http://www.hometownbrew.net/products/all)

You can also then use your views settings to group portions of content and much much more.